# When opening a text file that I will append I want to keep only the header that is the first couple of lines

Tags: python

How can I do this so that after appending when I run the code again it starts the file off fresh with only the header lines?

```
with open('svg5.svg','a+') as txt:
```

Comment: You can't.  You'll have to open it as `'r'`, read the lines you want to keep, then open it as `'w'` and start over.

Answer (score -1):

you can either append to everything or delete the content.

to keep a spefic string you can have a const like

```py
HEADER = "this is my nice looking header"
with open(filepath,'w') as outfile:
  outffile.write(HEADER)
  outfile.write(whatever you want)
```